# How can I call a JUnit test as the setup for another?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm trying to create a JUnit test that requires a user to log in with an admin account.
To make it so that I don't have to repeat code I've done a `Login` JUnit test and a `GoToAdminPage` JUnit test.

- The first accesses the login page and logs in.
- The second attempts to reach a menu only accessible by admins, and is meant to *pick up right where the first leaves off*. What I want is for `GoToAdminPage` is to start on the very same page and with the very same environment that `Login` ends.

The idea is that by creating a `Login` automated test, I can reuse it for whatever test I want to do in the future that requires admin rights.

What I'm trying to do is, in the `setUp()` of `GoToAdminPage`, call the first test.
However, what this does is that it launches a test browser for `GoToAdminPage`, and then immediately launches another test browser for `Login` which closes since `Login.tearDown()` contains a `driver.quit()` instruction.

What I want is for `GoToAdminPage` expects to pick up right on the same page `Login` ends, it has no `get` instruction so it never leaves the starting Firefox page.

I've already tried a couple of things. Each of my tests inherits the `BasicTest` class, which defines a number of things (WebDriver, JS Executor, generic utility functions, etc.). In that class, I created a `perform()` function that calls `setUp()` and `test()`.

That way, in `GoToAdminPage`, all I would have to do is call `Login.perform()` in `GoToAdminPage.setUp()`, and that would technically achieve what I want to do. However, it doesn't, and has the same effect as I mentioned above.

Looking online, I saw that I could also make it so that `GoToAdminPage extends Login`, but that also has the same result.

Finally I attempted to place the entire `Login.test()` process in a separate function in `Login` class that I could call inside `GoToAdminPage`, yet this has the same result.

In summation, what seems to be happening is that, when I call another JUnit test inside `GoToLoginPage`, it performs the test, but does it as a *separate test*.

What I want is to be able to essentially make it all one big test, where, once I've called `Login`, I can interact with the post-login page with my user logged in. 
Essentially I just want `GoToAdminPage` to be an extension of `Login`'s process.

Is this possible?

Here is my current code:

Login.java

```
public class Login extends BasicTest {

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        driver.get(constants.connectionUrl);
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.login(driver);
    }

    public void login(WebDriver d) throws InterruptedException {
        ...login process using webdriver....
    }
}
```

GoToAdminPage.java

```
public class GoToAdminPage extends BasicTest {

    Login Login = new Login();
    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Login.login(driver);
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ...post login test process...
    }
}
```

Yet still, this has the aforementioned effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the solution:

- `GoToAdminPage` extends `Login`
- `GoToAdminPage.setUp()` calls `parent.setUp()`
- `GoToAdminPage.test()` calls `parent.test()`

Using this I was able to make my second test use its parent as a setup phase.

Answer (score 0):

Define "log in" steps as a regular method (not annotated with `@Test`). Then you can call that method from wherever you want. From your login test method (adding required assertions after the steps have been performed) and from any `setUp` methods without actually running login test.

Comment: That is essentially what I did. I defined a `login()` method within my `Login` class, which I call in my `@Test` method in `Login`, and in my `@Before` method in `GoToAdminPage`. I'll put the code in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the [Page Object Pattern](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/), and create a login object page.

> One of the most popular patterns in Web Automation is the so called
> Page Object Pattern. To understand the primary goal of the pattern,
> first you need to think what your web automation tests are doing. They
> navigate to different web pages and click/type on/in various elements.
> The Page Object Pattern wraps all elements, actions and validations
> happening on a page in one single object- Page Object. [source](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/)

Some of the advantages of page object pattern as listed below,

- Reduces the duplication of code
- Makes tests more readable and robust
- Improves the maintainability of tests

IMHO creating dependencies between test cases is not a good practice.

Example:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public final class LoginPage {

    @FindBy(id="username")
    private WebElement username;

    @FindBy(id="password")
    private WebElement password;

    @FindBy(id="loginBtn")
    private WebElement submit;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void submit(String username, String password) {
        this.username.sendKeys(username);
        this.password.sendKeys(password);
        submit.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on a project where pages are made out of dynamic elements, and no page is ever guaranteed to exist except login pages. So my tests must be written on a module per module basis.

Still, I can adapt the POP to work with modules instead of pages. That is in essence what I am doing. Many of the practices that are recommended -- generalization and factorization to prevent code repetition and increase the amount of generic tests -- I was planning on using and will be using.

Thank you for the `FindBy` annotation, will be very helpful.